# javascript - ionRangeSlider dynamic values

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT: Added HTML (bottom)

Please forgive me as I am brand new to JS. I have a functional set of sliders, and would like to dynamically link the maximum value of slider(2) to the current value of slider(1). I am able to set the max for slider(2) as a variable of the current value of slider(1) - however, when I change the value of slider(1), it does not update the max of slider (2).

These are the default values set for slider(1):

```
    var singleOption1Title = 'Title';
    var singleOption1Price = 49;
    var actualQty1 = 10;
    var subSum1 = 490;
```

These are the onClick functions, applied to all sliders:

```
    $('#option1Single').on('click', function () {
        updateSummary();
        saveState();
        reValidateTotal();
    });
```

Expanding further:

```
    function updateSummary() {

        // Get the current data from option1Single elements     
        actualQty1 = $('#option1SingleQty').val();

        // Update order summary with option1Single details
        if (actualQty1 != 0) {

            subSum1 = (singleOption1Price * 1) * (actualQty1 * 1);
            $('#option1SingleSum').html('<span><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span> ' + singleOption1Title + ' x ' + actualQty1 + '<span class="price">' + subSum1.toFixed(2) + '</span>');
            formatItemPrice();

        }
...
```

```
    function saveState() {

        // Update hidden fields with option1Single details
        $('#option1Title').val(singleOption1Title);
        $('#option1Price').val(singleOption1Price);
        $('#subSum1').val(subSum1);
...
```

```
    function reValidateTotal() {

        $('#total').parsley().validate();
    }
```

Here is the configuration of slider(1):

```
    var $range = $('#option1SingleRangeSlider'),
        $input = $('#option1SingleQty'),
        instance,
        min = 0,
        max = 250;

    $range.ionRangeSlider({
        skin: 'round',
        type: 'single',
        min: min,
        max: max,
        from: 10,
        hide_min_max: true,
        onStart: function (data) {
            $input.prop('value', data.from);
        },
        onChange: function (data) {
            $input.prop('value', data.from);
            updateSummary();
            reValidateTotal();
            saveState();
        }
    });

    instance = $range.data("ionRangeSlider");

    $input.on('input', function () {
        var val = $(this).prop('value');

        // Validate
        if (val < min) {
            val = min;
            $input.val(min);
        } else if (val > max) {
            val = max;
            $input.val(max);
        }

        instance.update({
            from: val
        });

        updateSummary();

    });
```

I can link the max value of slider(2) to current value of slider(1):

```
var $range5 = $('#option5SingleRangeSlider'),
        $input5 = $('#option5SingleQty'),
        instance5,
        min5 = 0,
        max5 = actualQty1;

    $range5.ionRangeSlider({
        skin: 'round',
        type: 'single',
        min: min5,
        max: max5, 
        from: 0,
        step: 1,
        hide_min_max: true,
        onStart: function (data) {
            $input5.prop('value', data.from);
        },
        onChange: function (data) {
            $input5.prop('value', data.from);
            if (!singleOption5IsChecked) {
                activateSingleOption('option5Single');
            }
            updateSummary();
            reValidateTotal();
            saveState();
        }
    });

    instance5 = $range5.data("ionRangeSlider");

    $input5.on('input', function () {
        var val5 = $(this).prop('value');

        // Validate
        if (val5 < min5) {
            val5 = min5;
            $input5.val(min5);
        } else if (val5 > max5) {
            val5 = max5;
            $input5.val(max5);
        }

        instance5.update({
            from: val5
        });

        if (!singleOption5IsChecked) {
            activateSingleOption('option5Single');
        }

        updateSummary();
        reValidateTotal();
        saveState();

    });
```

The value, however, does not update when changed. Can someone tell me what I need to do in order to have the max value of slider(2) update on a change of slider(1)?

Please tell me if I'm missing anything that may help address a solution.

Here is the relevant HTML:

slider(1):

```
<div class="col-12">
  <input type="hidden" id="option1Title" name="option1Title" value="Title" />
  <input type="hidden" id="option1Price" name="option1Price" value="" />
  <label class="cbx" style="display: none;" for="option1Single">
    <span>
      <svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
        <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <span id="option1SingleTitle">Title</span>
  </label>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8 col-md-10">
      <input id="option1SingleRangeSlider" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
      <input id="option1SingleQty" type="text" class="qty-input form-control" name="optionGroup1Qty" value="0" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

slider(2):

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
  <input type="hidden" id="option5Title" name="option5Title" value="Title2" />
  <input type="hidden" id="option5Price" name="option5Price" value="" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="option5Single" class="inp-cbx" name="option5Single" value="20.00" />
  <label class="cbx" for="option5Single">
    <span>
      <svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
        <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <span id="option5SingleTitle">
      Title2
    </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide HTML so we can test it? thanks

Comment: @sample added, thank you for looking into it!

Comment: what does the `...` in the first two functions mean? Is there more code? If possible, can you make a code snippet (allows us to run your js directly in the browser)?

Comment: @sample - I have uploaded the files to pastebin; I hope this helps. Thank you. 
js - https://pastebin.com/NyTdRacd ; html - https://pastebin.com/04d7HhFH

Comment: CSS if it helps in testing - https://pastebin.com/L8dZRhng